# Android cannot find symbol method getMap()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I have a gps app that works fine on my phone. However, I see there were people having a null pointer exception in the production.

```
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 90);
```

The error I'm getting from production is 
Caused by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

So I did some research and find out that getMap method has been removed and people recommend using `getMapAsync(this);`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;    //which doesn't seem to work
}
```

However, I'm referencing the `googleMap` variable in many different methods, and I cannot move all the code to `onMapReady` method. I tried using `this.googleMap = googleMap` inside the `onMapReady` method, but I'm still getting null pointer exceptions whenever I try to reference the `googleMap` variable. I defined the getMapAsync(this) in onCreated(), and then try to access the 'googleMap' object in onResume() and getting the null pointer exception. Is there a way to fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the layout file ?

Comment: The whole purpose of Async method is to run your code when the operation is ready which is done asynchronously. So you cannot and should not run any code before that callback is called. You need to refactor your login to execute post that callback.

Answer (score 8):

You are getting null pointer exception because you are trying to use google map object but google map object is still null,so you need to follow this step.
write this code in onCreate() method

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

now impleents your class with `public class Demo implements OnMapReadyCallback` in short you need to override  onMapReady(Googlemap googleMap) methood.
you can perform all action after callback from onMapReady().

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
 // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: I created the above object in onCreate(), however, when I tried to use the googleMap object in onResume(), I'm stilling getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception in onResume() because your map is not ready yet.

Answer (score 4):

As I suggest in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323120/android-cannot-resolve-method-getmap/38323166#38323166) Answer.

`getMap()` is deprecated use `getMapAsync()` instead of it in the following way.

Replace this

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
```

with this

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMapAsync(this);
```

for more details visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)

Comment: The return type of getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallBack(){}) is void.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getMapAsync(this)` method. [Please check this link for more](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/06/marker-zindex-and-more-come-to-google.html)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
```

with

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you've mismatched the `SupportMapFragment` and `MapFragment` means if you have class attribute

```
class ="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

in your `XML` then you should use

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

**OR**

If you have class attr like

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

then you can do like as you are doing.