# MapView.getMap() is not supported in play-services 15.0

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-play-services

I have updated play services from `9.0.1` to `15.0.0`, now i am seeing that `MapView.getMap();` is no longer supported.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462506/4977669), I followed it and fixed the problem.

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

MapView mMapView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

}   

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

**Layout**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The issue is, I am using `MapView` and not `GoogleMap`, so i have just added `onMapReady()` method as its required by interface, but i am not doing anything in it.

Everything sees to be working fine, but should i change `MapView` to `GoogleMap`, or its fine, if i keep using `MapView` in `play-services:15.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need (and it's impossible) to replace `MapView` by `GoogleMap` because it's completely different: [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) `FrameLayout` - based view which displays a map  and  [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) is the entry point for all methods related to the map. So its fine keep using `MapView`.