# Error Andoid Studio : Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, maps

I have an error while trying to run the Signal application for Android. The error is as the following :

```
error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

And it is found in the `PlacePickerActivity.java` in the following line :

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Android docs:
[findFragmentById(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentById(int))

The findByFragmentId() function returns a `Fragment`, you cannot cast it to a `SupportMapFragment`.

You can try something like this:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();
```

Comment: Try using getMapAsync() like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323120/android-cannot-resolve-method-getmap/38323166]